# Unity GooglePlayGames error - APP crashes

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Alright, I'm trying everything to implement Google Play Service to my android app but nothing works. So I created new simple unity project just to try to make it work. I go to my google developer console - create new app - upload my simple unity project apk - then services & api - add new game - i set it up , make a leaderboard and i get its resources from export resources dialog.
(My Unity version is 5.5.4p4
I tried different API levels 14-23
I got GPGS plugins from here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity
i got it imported in my Unity project)

I go to window/GPGS/setup/android setup and I paste there everything from resources dialog.

in my simple c# script that is assigned to an object on a stage i have this:

```
void Start() {PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder ().Build ();PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance (config);PlayGamesPlatform.Activate (); SignIn();}

void SignIn() {Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {if(success) { ((GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SetGravityForPopups(Gravity.BOTTOM); Debug.Log("done");}else { Debug.Log("error");}});}
```

I also got addScoreToLeaderbords and showLeaderboardUI voids, i wrote it just like they said in manual but it's not that important because

MY APP ALWAYS CRASHES on start ( when I delete line in signin void it wont crash....).
any idea?
i tried downgrading a plugins to 10.0.1, but nothing works

Comment: add some exception handling so you can have more info on those crashes

Comment: App wont crash in Unity Game Editor, so it works... it wont login to gpgs because it cant be done from editor...But on device it crashes even if it's in try/catch block

Comment: This issue still exists and for me it's for showing the leaderboards, the only way to solve this is uninstalling the Google Play Games app and installing it again.